# Removal of Dash/Dots in a string column in pandas and replace it with Null

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, regexp-replace

I have the below data frame. In which the column "col1" is a string column consists of text, special characters, dash, dots, and dates.

I would like to substitute all entries in `col1` which **only** contain dashes and/or dots. They should be substituted with the word `null`. Remark that the dates in `col1` also contains dashes or dots. These I do not want to replace.

** Input:**

```
col1 

----
-
---
02-05-2018 meet with bm sir and service manager 
02-05-2018 meet with xyz sir for HA 
02-05-2018 meet with pqr sir for PAI 
04-12-2107
-
.
...
03.08.2018
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Col1

null
null
null
02-05-2018 meet with bm sir and service manager 
02-05-2018 meet with xyz sir for HA 
02-05-2018 meet with pqr sir for PAI 
04-12-2107
null
null
null
03.08.2018
```

Comment: I have clearly asked the question and given the relevant examples. @Scott Boston also came up with solution, unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Just because the solution is hard to find, doesn't account for it to be useless. Please ask me if its unclear rather than simple marking it down with no solution provided.

Answer (score 3):

Use `mask` and `contains` with regex:

```
df.mask(df.col1.str.contains(r'^[\.|\-]'))
```

Output:

```
                                              col1
0                                              NaN
1                                              NaN
2                                              NaN
3  02-05-2018 meet with bm sir and service manager
4              02-05-2018 meet with xyz sir for HA
5             02-05-2018 meet with pqr sir for PAI
6                                       04-12-2107
7                                              NaN
8                                              NaN
9                                              NaN
```

### Update with an additional column to show change.

```
df['col11'] = df.mask(df.col1.str.contains(r'^[\.|\-]'))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                               col1                                            col11
0                                              ----                                              NaN
1                                                 -                                              NaN
2                                               ---                                              NaN
3   02-05-2018 meet with bm sir and service manager  02-05-2018 meet with bm sir and service manager
4               02-05-2018 meet with xyz sir for HA              02-05-2018 meet with xyz sir for HA
5              02-05-2018 meet with pqr sir for PAI             02-05-2018 meet with pqr sir for PAI
6                                        04-12-2107                                       04-12-2107
7                                                 -                                              NaN
8                                                 .                                              NaN
9                                               ...                                              NaN
10                                       03.08.2018                                       03.08.2018
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know whose doing the downvote. 
I tried the code, it is not working. Its replacing with the numbers

Comment: replacing with numbers???  There is no replace in this statement, here we are masking where the contains returns True.  And, contains returns true if any character other than . or - is present in string.

Comment: Its basically replacing the values from the "first column" in my dataframe which is numbers. Below is the code i executed 

df['bn_note_text'] = df.mask(df.bn_note_text.str.contains(r'^[\.|\-]'))

bn_note_text is the column name i need to apply regex

Comment: Okay, am confused.   print df.head(10) before the statement run the statement you have here and print df.head(10) after the statement.

Comment: df['bn_note_text'].head()
Out[757]: 
0    63889
1    15351
2    15351
3    15351
4    34237

Comment: Still replacing it with the first column. Should I do some kind of preprocess before?

Comment: The first colum you mean the dataframe index?

Comment: No, not the index. The first columns values. The first column is "emp-id" and the 5th column is my "text" column. So, the result is replica of all the emp-id now

Answer (score -1):

Use `/^[-.]+$/gm` to match against only lines containing . or -

if you want to keep lines which contain only a mixture of dots and dashes you can use `/^([-.])\1*$/gm`